# How to merge two json file with jq with additional key

Tags: json, command-line, jq

I've got 2 json files and want to merge them into one unique file, but with additional key, for example "first_key" and "second_key"

Here the content of files:

File 1

```
{
  "timestamp": 1382461861,
  "value": {
      "aaa": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      },
      "bbb": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      },
      "ccc": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      }
   }
}
```

File 2

```
{
  "timestamp": 138246330,
  "value": {
      "ddd": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      },
      "eee": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      },
      "fff": {
          "value1": "v1",
          "value2": "v2"
      }
   }
}
```

expected result :

```
{ 
  "first_key" : {
    "timestamp": 1382461861,
    "value": {
        "aaa": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "bbb": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "ccc": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        }
     }
  },
  "second_key": {
    "timestamp": 138246330,
    "value": {
        "ddd": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "eee": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        },
        "fff": {
            "value1": "v1",
            "value2": "v2"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I try a lot of combinations but none of the result has the additional key as i expected. I'm also new at using jq so i really appreciate it if you could tell me command i should use. thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```sh
jq --slurp '{first_key:.[0], second_key:.[1]}' file1 file2
```

```sh
jq --null-input '{first_key:input, second_key:input}' file1 file2
```

```sh
jq --null-input '[inputs] | {first_key:.[0], second_key:.[1]}' file1 file2
```

```sh
jq --null-input --argfile f1 file1 --argfile f2 file2 '{first_key:$f1, second_key:$f2}'
```

```sh
jq --null-input --argjson f1 "$(<file1)" --argjson f2 "$(<file2)" '{first_key:$f1, second_key:$f2}'
```

```sh
jq --null-input --slurpfile f1 file1 --slurpfile f2 file2 '{first_key:$f1[0], second_key:$f2[0]}'
```

```sh
jq --null-input --slurpfile f <(cat file1 file2) '{first_key:$f[0], second_key:$f[1]}'
```

---

Notes

- `--slurp` can be abbreviated to `-s`
- `--null-input` can be abbreviated to `-n`
- `--argfile` is deprecated in favor of `--slurpfile`